# jquery .load() getScript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

several hours ago i posted a .load() and called script problem.

I kinda got it to work with .getScript() but i get mayor issue - The function is being executed several times.

this is the full code http://nikolafolio.in.rs/SPI.js

and the buggy part

```
   var LoadContentWrapper = href+' .pageloader_inner';

    $('#pageloader').delay(1000).queue(function() {

        $(this).load(LoadContentWrapper, function() {
            $('#loader').fadeOut(100);
            $('#pagecontent').slideDown(slideUpSpeed, $easingType, function() {
                $close_button.fadeIn(500);
                $.getScript('js/SPI.js');
            });
```

Comment: 1. Why are you using `queue`? 2. Try give a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) So we can see what's going on

Comment: Didn't work.. Still the same problem.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why u always load the SPI.js inside loadContent function if this function is inserted by the SPI.js ?

Try to build a small part of this app in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), this way will be easier to get help